# My Pivotal tc Server not Start

Tags: java, apache, spring-tool-suite

Until a few days ago, my STS worked perfectly, but of a sudden, the Pivotal server does not start, throws me the following error message when you run an application:

```
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0 (Native Method)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize (Win32FileSystem.java: 414)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath (File.java: 618)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile (File.java: 643)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader (ClassLoaderFactory.java: 170)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader (Bootstrap.java: 149)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders (Bootstrap.java: 90)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init (Bootstrap.java: 226)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main (Bootstrap.java: 425)
```

They could help me with this problem?

From already, thank you very much for your attention and time.

Gustavo Echenique

Comment: Have you moved or deleted something recently in your STS installation or your Tomcat installation?   It seems very unhappy with the location of some file that it's trying to read.   You may also want to see if any of your environment variables have been changed (CATALINA_HOME, etc)

Comment: Check the JRE for your server instance runtime environment. Perhaps Java was removed from that location and moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on Tomcat 6 (Pivotal 3.0, STS) and my problem was in catalina.properties. The "common.loader" property was incorrectly using Tomcat 8 style and it was as follows:

```
common.loader = \
\"${catalina.base}/lib\",\
\"${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar\",\
\"${catalina.home}/lib\",\
\"${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar\"
```

I have removed the double quotes and that fixed the problem. Correct definition:

```
common.loader = \
${catalina.base}/lib,\
${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,\
${catalina.home}/lib,\
${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar
```

Also, STS has quietly added Tomcat 8 JARs (bootstrap.jar, etc) to my Tomcat 6 launch configuration. While I had these JARs on the classpath, everything worked fine. But once I discovered and removed them, Tomcat 6 started breaking with the error in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I started to have the same issue out of nothing as well. We are using Java 1.7 in our project, but I also have Java 8 installed on my machine for experimenting. Even though everything is still configured to use 1.7 (I never changed the configuration and it was working fine), I think after some Java 8 update  I started to get this issue.

After trying several things, I decided to uninstall all Java 8 related updates and installations; and made a fresh installation of Spring STS 3.6.2 with a new workspace. It seems to be working fine right now. You can try this if you also have a similar environment.